# GCP IAM User Deletion Log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, activitylog

Few days back, two user IDs got missing from multiple Google Cloud Platform project's IAM. As of now the access has been restored but there is no IAM deletion log present in any of the related project's activity log. Even not able to detect any using log explorer.

Kindly suggest if there is any workaround to find out the IAM deletion record or any log related to this incident.

[Note: There is no subscription for Google Technical support]

Comment: Admin Activity audit logs are always enabled; you can't disable them. You can read more at: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging

Comment: Thanks Armando. Checked the Admin Activity log but found nothing related to those IDs. I know it is strange but I am stuck here.

Comment: You are either looking in the wrong log or overlooking those entries.